# Does JavaScript have an equivalent of VBScript's ExecuteGlobal?

Tags: javascript, vbscript

Is there any alternative of ExecuteGlobal in javascript?

```
Function vbExecuteGlobal(parmSCRIPT)
    ExecuteGlobal(parmSCRIPT)
End Function
```

DevGuru [describes the statement] such:

> The ExecuteGlobal statement takes a single string argument, interprets it as a VBScript statement or sequence of statements, and executes these statements in the global namespace.

Comment: If something executes a string as code, the solution is to refactor it so it doesn't. You should not keep code in strings.

Comment: You "could" use `setTimeout(code, 0)`... but are you sure you really need this? I agree with Quentin here.

Comment: @FelixKling — I was going to suggest that (with dire warnings), but there is a minimum timeout in most JS engines, and it evaluates the code asynchronously.

Comment: Can you please clarify, do you want to evaluate javascript in javascript globally or vbscript in javascript?

Comment: actually i am doing cross browser codeing and i have some old code which is in mixture of vbscript & javascript and except IE none of the browser support vbscript.So they are calling this vbscript function in javascript which working fine only in IE so how can i do in javascript... i want to evaluate javascript in javascript or any other solution you have.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Javascript equivalent to VBScript's Execute[Global] is eval(). The passed code is evaluated in the context of the call.

See [here for details, pros and cons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

**UPDATE**

Not to recommend such practices, but to clarify my understanding of equivalence:

```
// calling eval in global context is the exact equivalent of ExecuteGlobal
eval("function f0() {print('f0(): yes, we can!');}");
f0();

// calling eval in locally is the exact equivalent of Execute
function eval00() {
  eval("function f1() {print('f1(): no, we can not!');}");
  f1();
}
eval00();
try {
  f1();
}
catch(e) {
  print("** error:", e.message);
}

// dirty trick to affect global from local context
function eval01() {
  eval("f2 = function () {print('f2(): yes, we can use dirty tricks!');}");
  f2();
}
eval01();
f2();
```

output:

```
js> load("EvalDemo.js")
f0(): yes, we can!
f1(): no, we can not!
** error: "f1" is not defined.
f2(): yes, we can use dirty tricks!
f2(): yes, we can use dirty tricks!
```

So: Problems that can be solved using Execute[Global] in VBScript can be solved using eval() in Javascript; for some problems extra work or tricks may be necessary.

As Abhishek explicitly said "i want to evaluate javascript in javascript", I don't feel the need to justify my answer.

Comment: Even in your answer you say that it evaluates in the context of the call (not global) so you must know it's not equivalent. So why the answer?