# Eval in global scope under wscript

Tags: eval, jscript, wsh, msscriptcontrol

Is there a way to fully emulate a global `eval()` call from within a function call? I've tried various methods and cannot find a suitable solution that works under wscript:

```
var Global = this;
function globalEval(code) {
    (1, eval).call(Global, code);
}
globalEval('var foo = "bar"');
WScript.echo(foo); // undefined
```

Other methods I've tried:

```
eval.call(Global, code);
Global.eval.call(Global, code);
new Function(code);
(1, eval)(code)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fully emulate"?

Comment: All variables, functions, etc created by the eval that are NOT wrapped in a function are created in the global scope

Comment: [`.call()` is totally not necessary](http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/)

Comment: So you don't want to emulate anything, you just want to make a global eval call but it doesn't work?

Comment: yes, just a global scoped call; I tried without the `.call()` to no avail, just didn't remember to list it with the other methods tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11467759/692942

Comment: Suggested duplicate seems off as the specified question is talking about browser environments opposed to wscript; furthermore, no valid answer was given.

Comment: @SReject Correction the OP just never bothered to accept an answer, the issue is the same whether it's script in a browser or directly in a scripting engine. `ExecuteGlobal` in VBScript does exactly what the you are asking for there has no direct equivalent in JScript *(WSH doesn't use JavaScript, it uses Microsoft's own proprioraty version of ECMAScript)* but it can be done using `eval();`.

Comment: @Hacketo Again WSH *(Windows Scripting Host)* uses JScript **not** JavaScript [you can't make direct comparisons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4tc5a343.aspx).

Comment: @Lankymart: You say it could be done using `eval` but apparently it doesn't work for the OP. Of course, `eval` works when executed in the global scope, but that's not what we have here. We would need indirect eval. Does JScript have that?

Comment: @Bergi Agreed, but may be this will help - [Why does VBScript have Execute, ExecuteGlobal and Eval?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/20/why-does-vbscript-have-execute-executeglobal-and-eval/)

Comment: @Hacketo True but the point I'm making is they are different. `eval()` may indeed behave the same but according to the OP it doesn't.

Comment: @Bergi Does JScript have indirect eval? Your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: @Hacketo: `(1, eval)`, and everything with `.call`, is an indirect call, that's fine and *should* work (in JavaScript, at least)

Comment: @Bergi If we are talking about JavaScript which we are not. This is where the confusion comes in, in that article I linked I think this line is probably the clincher *"The long and short of it is that if you want to affect the global name space, you have to do it explicitly"*.

Comment: @Lankymart: thanks, that article is a good find. The statement you cited does indeed suggest that there is no way to do this.

Comment: @Bergi Flexing my [Google Fu](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/19973/99025).

Comment: Here's another interesting article from the man himself *([Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert))* - [Eval is Evil, Part Three](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/01/26/eval-is-evil-part-three/) *(Bear in mind this Guy help develop VBScript, JScript and WScript amongst others)*. The article is talking about JScript.Net but the underlying engine is the same.